# Convert string that is basically a nested array of integers to an array and display an image

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I have an array coming from a get request that is returned to me as a string, in this form: [[[red [row data],[row data]],[blue [row data],[row data]]…]. It is essentially an image with 3-tuples of 0-255 values representing RGB values, and I am trying to display it in my React app as an image. Heres also a snippet of the array: "[[[68, 81, 237], [67, 80, 236], [64, 79, 235], [61, 79, 234], [62, 80, 235], [61, 81, 236], [61, 83, 238], [62, 84, 239], [62, 84, 239], [62, 84, 239],"

What is the easiest way to convert this into some type of image I can display on a web page?

Comment: How do you want to show the image? You can think of using canvas to generate the image,

Comment: I'm not exactly sure the best way to do it. I just came here for suggestions

Answer (score 1):

You can render `div`s as to be pixels and draw it as below by using [Array.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) twice to iterate over the `rows` and `columns`. Use a 2D array to store the color information. You can adjust the pixel size by changing the `width` and `height` styles.

```js
const data = [
  [
    [6, 81, 237],
    [67, 0, 236],
    [64, 79, 23]
  ],
  [
    [61, 79, 234],
    [20, 220, 15],
    [6, 33, 106]
  ],
  [
    [255, 83, 238],
    [62, 84, 239],
    [62, 228, 229]
  ]
];

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      {data.map((row) => (
        <div style={{ display: "flex" }}>
          {row.map(([red, green, blue]) => (
            <div
              style={{
                backgroundColor: `rgb(${red},${green},${blue})`,
                width: "30px",
                height: "30px"
              }}
            ></div>
          ))}
        </div>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(<App/>, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: @TeaganShep, check this out !!